# Is this correct? $rH=Hr^{-1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is this reasoning correct ?

$g∈rH$
$⇔∃h∈H: g=rh$
$⇔h=r^{-1}g$
$⇔h^{-1}=g^{-1}r$
$⇔∃(h'=h^{-1}∈H): g=h' r^{-1}$
$⇔g∈Hr^{-1}$

Therefore $rH=Hr^{-1}$

Comment: Ah, now I'm a little concerned that you may have misapplied my hint for [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/330236/show-that-the-set-r-1-r-in-r-contains-exactly-one-element-out-of-eac/330240#330240).  Could you perhaps add an answer to that question showing your proof?

Comment: In line -2, you cannot have $g=h'r^{-1}$; you only have that $g^{-1}=h'r^{-1}$, so $g=rh'^{-1}$.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the question Tara B links to.

Comment: Indeed!  I hope nobody thought I was indicating it is.

Comment: $h^{-1}=g^{-1}r$ need not imply that $g=h'r^{-1}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you're wrong. Take $G = S_3$, $H = \{1, (12)\}$, $r = r^{-1} = (13)$. Then $$r H = (13) \{1,(12)\}=\{(13), (132)\} \ne \{ (13) (123)\} = \{1, (12)\} (13) = H r^ {-1}.$$

The mistake is when you go from $h^{-1}=g^{-1}r$ to $g=h^{-1} r^{-1}$. The latter should be $g^{-1} = h^{-1} r^{-1}$ instead.

**PS** In [this other post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/330236/show-that-the-set-r-1-r-in-r-contains-exactly-one-element-out-of-eac) it is noted that if $R$ is a complete set of representative for the left cosets of $H$ in $G$, that is, every such coset can be written uniquely as $r H$, for some $r \in R$, then $R^{-1} = \{r^{-1} : r \in R\}$ is a complete set of representative for the right cosets of $H$ in $G$, that is, every such coset can be written uniquely as $H r^{-1}$, for some $r \in R$. This does not clash with what is happening here, as a left coset need not be a right coset.

**PPS** Perhaps I could add a simple observation. Let $H$ be a subgroup of a group $G$, and suppose $r H = H r^{-1}$ for some $r \in G$. Then $r = h r^{-1}$ for some $h \in H$, so $r^2 = h \in H$. Moreover $r H r^ {-1} = r^2 H = H$. Conversely if $r \in N_G(H)$ and  $r^2 \in H$, then $H r^{-1} = r^2 H r^{-1} = r r H r^{-1} = r H$.

Comment: Ah, I just added an answer pointing out where the mistake was, but now your answer is complete!

Comment: @Kasper, you're welcome!

Answer (score 4):

As Andreas Caranti has pointed out, the statement itself is not correct.

Where you went wrong in your reasoning is the second-to-last line.  You are claiming $g = h^{-1}r^{-1}$.  But $g = rh$, so this is only true if $g = g^{-1}$, that is, if $g$ has order at most $2$.

Comment: Precisely! I had just added something like that in an edit.

Comment: I know.  I saw your edit just after I added my answer.  I would not have bothered otherwise.  I guess I'll still leave this up, since we've phrased things differently.

Comment: By all means leave your answer up, it definitely adds value to the conversation.